# How declare non standard array belong to class?

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I have a VBA class:

```
Option Explicit

Public Re As Double 'Real
Public Im As Double 'Imaginary


Public Function CZ_Sqt(Z As Complex, Exp As Integer) As Variant  
   Dim Table() As Complex
   Dim i As Integer

   If Exp > 0 Then
       ReDim Preserve Table(0 To Exp - 1)
       Set Table(UBound(Table)) = New Complex

   Else: Exit Function
   End If

   For i = 0 To UBound(Table)
      Table(i).Re = 1
      Table(i).Im = 1
   Next i
   set CZ_Sqt = Table 

End Function
```

In module:

```
Sub asd()
    Dim K As Complex
    Dim A As Variant

    Set K = New Complex


    K.Re = 1
    K.Im = 3
    Set A = K.CZ_Sqt(Z, 5)
end sub
```

1. How "set" all variable "Table" in on step ?
   In solution which is in example is set only element Table(4) but other elements are omited.
2. How to return this variable "Table" to the function name "CZ_Sqt" ?
   This what I proposed doesn't work.
3. How pass variable "CZ_Sqt" which consider Array Complex type to the variable "A"?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same class as an object and object collection.

I would separate the functionalities into 2 Classes:

- Complex
- ComplexCollection - Contains a collection of complex class

EDIT: There is no duplicate check in ComplexCollection.Add and exists check in ComplexCollection.Retrieve.

Complex

```
Option Explicit

Public Re As Double
Public Im As Double
```

ComplexCollection

```
Option Explicit

Dim oCol As Collection

Public Function Create(pRe As Double, pIm As Double) As Complex
    Dim oResult As Complex
    Set oResult = New Complex
    oResult.Re = pRe
    oResult.Im = pIm

    Set Create = oResult
End Function

Public Sub Add(pComplex As Complex, pKey As String)
     oCol.Add pComplex, pKey
End Sub

Public Function Retrieve(pKey As String) As Complex
     Set Retrieve = oCol(pKey)
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oCol = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set oCol = Nothing
End Sub
```

Test.bas

```
Public Sub TestCollection()
    Dim oCL As ComplexCollection
    Dim oC As Complex

    Set oCL = New ComplexCollection

    Set oC = oCL.Create(1, 2)
    Debug.Print oC.Im, oC.Re

    oCL.Add oC, "1"

    Set oC = Nothing
    Set oC = oCL.Retrieve("1")

    Debug.Print oC.Im, oC.Re

End Sub
```